# Cannot open COM port on ESP32 device. Using Windows10 and MPFShell

Tags: esp32, micropython

I can open my ESP32 Vroom32 device made by Espressif with a cp2101 chip on Ubuntu. I used Ubuntu to flash Micropython onto it, however when I try to connect with Putty, MPFshell or anything else on Windows 10 it will not work. I downloaded and installed the recommended drivers for it and also updated Windows which was supposed to load the driver as well. I can see the device and COM port in device manager but when I attempt to connect I get blocked. For example on MPFshell I get the message `"Cannot connect to COM17"`

Comment: What is the value of  "Serial Line" and "Speed" in Putty?

Comment: @George Bou COM16 and baud rates from 57600 - 460800.

Comment: Have you tried the speed 115200? and what's the error message you get on Putty? (also the port is COM16 or COM17 because you mentioned both?)

Comment: @GeorgeBou sorry about the port confusion. It was on port 17 earlier, plugged it in again and now it’s on COM16. Yes I’ve tried 115200

Comment: and what does Putty say in the error message? also in the device manager does the esp look properly connected?

Comment: @GeorgeBou I opened device manager and I'm getting a driver error (code 10). I reinstalled the latest driver form Silabs several times, rebooted, and still nothing.

Comment: try using another USB cable. it worked for me in the past in a similar case.

Comment: Gosh... the USB cable did the trick. Been scratching my head all day. I took the cable off of a perfectly good Arduino. Who would have thought it? Even the new cable that I'm using only works about half of the time. Do you know of a reliable source of cables for these things? @GeorgeBou

Comment: Just pick one from a good brand and make sure its for Data transfer, not only for charging. Glad it worked out for you!

Answer (score 0):

It is a common reason for boards to show the `"Cannot Connect to COM"` error because of a bad USB cable.

Always check with another cable first, before getting deeper to the problem.